# Creating Image objects out of local file drag'n'drop events in HTML5

Tags: javascript, image, html, drag-and-drop

I am looking for information about accessing images on the local file system access through drag'n' drop. I purpose is to allow the user to drag and drop images, read the data and output some  manipulation out of them.

I have not been very succesful finding good source material how to create Images() out of drag and drop events. I'd appreciate any pointeres.

Something is vaguely mentioned here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Images

The target is to support Webkit/Firefox browsers - IE is not a great concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/janposselt/mimedrop) jQuery plugin. The example let you drop one or more images (decided by the mime type of the dropped files) at a time and insert them as img-tags. The example does not use the images path but insert the content as data-url to an image src attribute.